# Is it possible to increase destination point radius?

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

When navigation starts and user reaches it's destination, this method will fire:

```
- (void)routingServiceDidReachDestination:(SKRoutingService *)routingService{}
```

Now, my question is, is there any way to increase the radius for location, so that it fires 20-30 meters before the user reaches the destination?

Since we're using 3rd party data, sometimes our locations are not 100% accurate, and they have some 10-20 meters error and in that case, user will never reach it's destination.